# Unbounded variation $\frac{1}{x}$

Tags: real-analysis, bounded-variation

How to formally prove that $$f(x)= \frac{1}{x} , \quad x \in(0,1]$$ is not of bounded variation.
Which partition should I try?

Comment: what exactly do you want to prove?

Comment: Oh sorry, I edited the question. My bad.

Comment: You should definitely not try subpartitions of $(1-2^{-n}\,:\, n\ge1)$.

Comment: Wikipedia defines the variation for closed intervals $[a,b]$, how do you define this for $(0,1]$?

Comment: Ok, so let's say that $f(0)=2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting $f(0)=2$ arbitrarily, we can show that $f\notin BV([0,1])$ by considering the partitions
$$ \mathcal P_n =\{x_0,x_1,x_2\}= \{ 0,2^{-n},1\}.$$
Thus
$$ V_0^1(f) \ge  |f(x_1)-f(x_2)| =2^n-1 \to \infty. $$